# Too many okhttp connection threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, retrofit2, okhttp

I am developing an android App using Retrofit2 to fetch massive data from my server. The retrofit API calls are performed in an IntentService. The downloaded data will be stored in SQLite database using Room. There are over a few hundreds of API calls. The first around 300 calls went well. However the app crashes quickly due to the error of `E/NativeCrypto: AppData::create pipe(2) failed: Too many open file`. I looked into the Profiler graph and I can see there are so many OkHttp Connections have been built up and threads grow very fast. The app crashes when the threads reached around 350.

Below is how retrofit is configured:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
    dispatcher.setMaxRequests(100);
    dispatcher.setMaxRequestsPerHost(50);


    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .dispatcher(dispatcher);
    builder.authenticator(new TokenAuthenticator(this)); 
    okHttpClient = builder
            .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(100, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .build();
    gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
            .create();
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl(MainApplication.API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
DownloadApiCalls downloadapiservice = retrofit.create(DownloadApiCalls.class);
```

Below is my API interface:

```
public interface DownloadApiCalls {

@GET("Download/test2")
Call<String> test2(@Query("name") String name);

@GET("Download/GetTaskList")
Call<List<Project>> GetTaskList(@Query("userid") String userid);

@GET("Download/GetTaskOwnerList")
Call<List<Account>> GetTaskOwnerList(@Query("userid") String userid);

@GET("Download/GetBusinessAreasList")
Call<List<BusinessArea>> GetBusinessAreasList(@Query("userid") String userid);

@GET("Download/GetSiteCategoryList")
Call<List<SiteCategory>> GetSiteCategoryList(@Query("accountid") String accountid);

// there are lots of API calls....
}
```

the API calls are within a loop given the business logic nature. (There are a few hundreds sites, each site has many different types of data to be downloaded.) Below is how I make calls:

```
for (final Site s : siteList) {
Call call_processblock = service.GetProcessBlockList(s.Id, lastSyncTime);
            call_processblock.enqueue(new Callback<List<ProcessBlock>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<ProcessBlock>> call, Response<List<ProcessBlock>> r) {
                    if (r.isSuccessful() && r.code() == 200) {
                        List<ProcessBlock> thelist = r.body();
                        AsyncTask.execute(
                        // database operations
                        );
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<ProcessBlock>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });


            Call call_streams = service.GetProcessStreamList(s.Id, lastSyncTime);
            call_streams.enqueue(new Callback<List<ProcessStream>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<ProcessStream>> call, Response<List<ProcessStream>> r) {
                    if (r.isSuccessful() && r.code() == 200) {
                        List<ProcessStream> thelist = r.body();
                        AsyncTask.execute(
                        //database operations
                        );
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<ProcessStream>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

            Call call_lines = service.GetProcessLineList(s.Id, lastSyncTime);
            call_lines.enqueue(new Callback<List<ProcessLine>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<ProcessLine>> call, Response<List<ProcessLine>> r) {
                    if (r.isSuccessful() && r.code() == 200) {
                        AsyncTask.execute(
                        // database operations
                        );

                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<ProcessLine>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
// there are other many API calls for the site
}
```

As per I mentioned at beginning, the app runs well until the threads reached around 350. Below is the debug output:

```
E/CursorWindow: CursorWindow create() failed with -24 errno
Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/user/0/com.gridenvironment.ufe/databases/ufe-database.db' of size 2097152 due to error -24.
E/NativeCrypto: AppData::create pipe(2) failed: Too many open files
W/zygote: ashmem_create_region failed for 'indirect ref table': Too many open files
E/NativeCrypto: AppData::create pipe(2) failed: Too many open files
E/NativeCrypto: AppData::create pipe(2) failed: Too many open files
```

Below is the snapshot of the Profiler:
[Too many OkHttp Connections threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NwBU.png)

Have I done anything incorrectly? Why are there so many OkHttp Connections are built up and not released?
Thanks.

Comment: You're executing the calls in a loop for each site, meaning that you'll always have several concurrent threads running.  Is it not possible for you to go to the next site  only after one site has finished processing?

Comment: Looks like you are not closing the response. See https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html

Comment: Also:  design-wise you don't want "a thread per request," nor "a thread that services only one request in its lifetime."  The number of threads that exist should be fixed and adjustable.  They sit there waiting on some queue, then pop a request off the queue, carry it out and wait again.  They might process an indefinite number of requests, or only a certain number after which they "commit hari kiri" as a way of cleaning themselves up.  (The parent notices this and spawns another.)

Comment: I have tried the following ways, neither worked.
1. put the loop body in a callable object to wait for finishing processing.
2. Retrofit2 closes response automatically. I cannot find a way to close the retrofit response after it's body has been converted.
3. I tried to limited the number of threads by pass a FixedThreadPool to Dispatcher of OkHttp. 
Any ideas? Thanks.